# How to store cookies, and reuse them in another session

Tags: java, android, cookies, rss, webview

I am trying to authenticate a user from a web page, 
store the cookies and load an rss-feed from a different web page as the authenticated user.

Im using a webView with this WebViewClient which loads an RSS-link when the user has authenticated himself (url is finished loading): - This does not redirect until after user logs in and presses another link.. How can I redirect straight after login?

```
class LinkWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    //Callback method for when the url is finished loading
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        view.loadUrl("https://something.com/todays-rssfeeds");
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

    };


}
```

Main Problem is when i try to load the second page, i have to re-authenticate myself because it is not the same session..

Any suggestions to how i can solve these problems?

These are my Cookie settings:

/

```
/ use cookies to remember a logged in status   
            CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this); 
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 

            //After Login
            List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (!cookies.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    cookie = cookies.get(i);
                }
            }

            Cookie sessionCookie = cookie; 

            if(sessionCookie != null)
            { 
                String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName()        +"="+sessionCookie.getValue()+"; domain="+sessionCookie.getDomain(); 
                cookieManager.setCookie(myUrl, cookieString); 
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync(); 
            }
```

All help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are tied to domain, but if these pages share authentication system (unlikely, I think), you could manually  pass session identifier to the second page. If not, the question is how that second page should authorize user?